# Recaptcha invisible

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

При подключении recaptcha invisible, необходимо указывать параметр data-callback, можно стандартно в колбек функции сделать сабмит определенной формы. Но как быть, если на странице 2 или более формы с recaptcha ? Как определить какую форму сабмитить ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемная эта invisible recaptcha =)

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="first-name-1"> <br />
<input type="text" name="last-name-1"> <br />
<div class="recaptcha-holder"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br />
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="first-name-2"> <br />
<input type="text" name="last-name-2"> <br />
<div class="recaptcha-holder"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

var renderGoogleInvisibleRecaptcha = function() {
for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; ++i) {
var form = document.forms[i];
var holder = form.querySelector('.recaptcha-holder');
if (null === holder){
continue;
}
(function(frm){
var holderId = grecaptcha.render(holder,{
'sitekey': 'CHANGE_ME_WITH_YOUR_SITE_KEY',
'size': 'invisible',
'badge' : 'bottomright', // possible values: bottomright, bottomleft, inline
'callback' : function (recaptchaToken) {
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(frm);
}
});
frm.onsubmit = function (evt){
evt.preventDefault();
grecaptcha.execute(holderId);
};
})(form);
}
};

</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=renderGoogleInvisibleRecaptcha&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```